# Reference on indexed hash

Tags: perl

I have such hash:

```
%output[$n]{"$names"}
```

where n - numbers = [0,1..n] (means records)
      $names - hash keys  {"key","moi","hy",..} (means name of columns)

How to:
1) count how many records шт hash
2) for each record get name of fields
3) get value of each element for each record in cycle ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't figure out what the question is. Could you illustrate with some code perhaps? That syntax isn't valid. Try printing your structure with `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%output;`

Comment: If you have a structure like that then `%output` should be an array `@output`

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You've set up a hash when you should have an array. You must also realise that Perl hashes are *unordered*, so if you need to display the fields in a particular order then you need a different strategy

However, to answer your questions

The number of records is

```
my $nrec = keys %output;
```

And you can iterate over the hash like this. For each record, `@names` is set to the names of the fields while `@values` is set to their corresponding values

```
for my $n ( sort { $a <=> $b } keys %output ) {
    my $rec = $output{$n};
    my @names = keys %$rec;
    my @values = values %$rec;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
%output[$n]{"$names"}
```

makes no sense. The closest thing that makes sense is

```
$output[$n]{"$names"}
```

You might also be using

```
$output->[$n]{"$names"}
```

In neither case do you have a hash.

---

In the first case, you have an array (`@output`) of references (`$output[$i]`) to hashes (`%{ $output[$i] }`).

To find the number of elements in an array, evaluate it in scalar context. For example,

```
my $size = @output;

say 0+@output;
```

---

In the first case, you have a reference (`$output`) to an array (`@$output`) of references (`$output->[$i]`) to hashes (`%{ $output->[$i] }`).

To find the number of elements in an array, evaluate it in scalar context. For example,

```
my $size = @$output;

say 0+@$output;
```